# Xamarin.iOS adding button programmatically to UITableViewCell- nothing happens when clicking it

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to learn how to add uiviews programmatically to my UITableViewCell. I know I can add it through the storyboard but I need it to be programmatically.

For testing I have added below code. When I click on the button nothing happens, my test method is never called. What am I missing?

```
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier) as TestCell;

            var cellWidth = cell.Frame.Width;
            var cellheight = cell.Frame.Height;

        UIButton testing = new UIButton();
        testing.SetTitle("TestBtn", UIControlState.Normal);
        testing.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, cellWidth, cellheight);
        testing.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
        testing.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => { test(); };
        testing.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        
        cell.AddSubview(testing);
        return cell;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that the controls should be added on `Cell.ContentView`.Please refer to my below code in `ViewController`:

```
  protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            UITableView _tableView = new UITableView(View.Bounds);
            string[] data = new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
            _tableView.DataSource = new CustomCellDataSource();

            this.View.AddSubview(_tableView);   
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        }


        public class CustomCellDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
        {
            public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("111");
                if(cell == null)
                {
                    cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default,"111");
                    cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
                }

                UIButton testing = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
                testing.SetTitle("TestBtn", UIControlState.Normal);
              
                testing.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
                nfloat w = cell.Frame.Width;
                nfloat h = cell.Frame.Height;
                testing.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, w, h);

                cell.ContentView.AddSubview(testing);
                return cell;
            }

            public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
            {
                return 4;
            }
        }

        public class CustomCellDelegate: UITableViewDelegate
        {
            [Export("tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:")]
            public nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                return 40;
            }
        }
```

[Reference link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/customizing-table-appearance#creating-custom-cell-layouts)